# How laravel handle file read write concurrently

Tags: php, laravel, concurrency, locking, laravel-9

I am writing a laravel 9 api. Sometimes it needs to handle local file read/write. I concern about the issue of read/write concurrently so I try to use file lock.

I know that the read/write function for local storage can be handled by this:

```
$content= Storage::disk('public')->get($path);
Storage::disk('public')->put($path, $newContent);
```

However, I can't find any laravel tool to handle the file lock. So, I am using the php way to do so:

```
$content= file_get_contents($path);
$file = fopen($path, 'w');
if (flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {
    try {
        // do somethings
        fwrite($file, $newContent);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
        //dd($e->getMessage());
    } finally {
        flock($file, LOCK_UN); 
    }
}else{
    // locked, fail
}
fclose($file);
```

Does laravel provide file lock or any better ways to handle file read/write concurrently?

Comment: Depending on your storage config - [`public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)`](https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/3a9ccfed2736a4629677167377a0e841ffd61cdb/Filesystem.php#L203)

Comment: @user1191247 so \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage does not support locking?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are saying. You need to pass `true` as the third argument to `put`, as the default is `false`. This is then passed through to [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) as `LOCK_EX` in the `flags` param.

Comment: @Kenzo In Laravel, the Storage facade does not provide built-in support for file locking, you can check [api docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Storage.html).